# record is read only : I am facing error while i am add the rest api response and update contarct though apex trigger

Tags: apex, rest-api

```
trigger RestAPIcalloutTrigger on Contract (after insert, after Update) {
    APIResponseCaseData APIRes = New APIResponseCaseData();
    List<Contract> conList = [SELECT Id, BCR_Case_Id__c FROM Contract WHERE 
        Broker_involved__c = 'Yes' ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1];
    for(Contract c : Trigger.New) {
        if(c.Broker_Involved__c ==  'yes' ) { 
            CreateCasesByContract.CreateCase(c.Id);
            c.BCR_Case_Id__c = APIRes.ResponseContent; 
            conList.add(c);
        }

        try {
            update conList;
        } catch(Exception ex) { 
            System.debug('Could not update CaseId in contract'  );
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: DML inside a FOR loop is a bad practice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant update records from the `Trigger.new` value. You have to query those records and then update them. `Trigger.new` is read-only. Hope this helps you!

EDIT: and if possible make a static class to check for recursive updates in case that may happen.